# Flex Data Binding

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, flex3

I'm trying to databind an object's property to a ComboBox's (editable=true) text property. This property is of type Number.

If I bind using the inline syntax, it works:

```
<mx:ComboBox text="{myObj.prop}">
```

If I bind using mx:Binding, I receive an error:

```
<mx:Binding source="{myObj.prop}" destination="combobox.text" />

// 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type String.
```

Why this difference in behaviour?

Property definition:

```
private var _prop: Number;

[Bindable] public function get prop(): Number { return _prop; }
public function set prop(value: Number): void { _prop = value; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Initially I thought:**
The `mx:Binding` source should be the field name itself, not the value.  Flex is complaining because it is dereferencing `myObj.prop` because of the `{}` and seeing the value there (a `Number`) when it wants a string with the field name.

```
<mx:Binding source="myObj.prop" destination="combobox.text" />
```

**However:**

ActionScript inside curly braces is allowed in the `mx:Binding` source expression, and is required in this case. See Adobe's [data binding examples](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_5.html).

The `text` property is expecting a `String` to be assigned to it, so you will want to cast in your binding:

```
<mx:Binding source="{String(myObj.prop)}" destination="combobox.text" />
```

My apologies for the initial misleading answer, hopefully this is on the right track.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the definition of `myObj.prop`.